# spidev ioctl return Invalid argument error

Tags: c++, linux, spi

I created a simple program to send spi messages using spidev.

I have two Raspberry pi 4 model B, one with Ubuntu and the other with the Raspberrypi OS.
The program works on Ubuntu, but it does not on the Rasperrypi OS.
It returns a `Invalid argument` error when trying to send a message using `SPI_IOC_MESSAGE` via ioctl. Configuring the spi device with using `SPI_IOC_WR_MODE` via ioctl works.

When looking at `spidev.h`, the following statement is made about `spi_ioc_transfer`

> NOTE: struct layout is the same in 64bit and 32bit userspace.

Based on this, the problem should not come from the architecture difference.

What should be the correct way to send a message here ?

Here is the code sample.

```
char *device = "spidev0.0";
fd = open(device, O_RDWR);

if (fd < 0)
{
    cout << "Can't open " << device << endl;
    return 1;
}

int mode = SPI_MODE_0;
int ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &mode);

if (ret < 0)
{
    cout << "Can't set the spi mode : " << endl
               << strerror(errno) << endl;
    close(fd);
    return 1;
}

struct spi_ioc_transfer xfer;
uint8_t buf[34];
memset(&xfer, 0, sizeof xfer);
xfer.tx_buf = (unsigned long)buf;
xfer.rx_buf = (unsigned long)buf;
xfer.len = 34;

int status = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), xfer);
if (status < 0)
{
    cout << "Ioctl error : " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Ubuntu runs the following kernel in 64bits

```
uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-1042-raspi #46-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 30 00:35:40 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

RasberryOS runs the following kernel in 32bits

```
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.71-rt24-v7l+ #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Mon Aug 30 14:52:43 CEST 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Edit:

tx and rx buffer are the same but the spidev [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spidev) states

> To make a full duplex request, provide both rx_buf and tx_buf for the
> same transfer.  It's even OK if those are the same buffer.

Doing `xfer.tx_buf = (uint64_t)buf;` results in the same error.

Comment: Please try `xfer.tx_buf = (uint64_t)buf;` and similar for `rx`.

Comment: Is it unhappy about the tx_buf and rx_buf being the same?  Try two different buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like changing

```
int status = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), xfer);
```

to

```
int status = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &xfer);
```

resolves the problem.

This respects the example of the documentation of `spidev.h`

> SPI_IOC_MESSAGE gives userspace the equivalent of kernel spi_sync().
> Pass it an array of related transfers, they'll execute together.
> Each transfer may be half duplex (either direction) or full duplex.
>
> struct spi_ioc_transfer mesg[4];
>
> status = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(4), mesg);

I don't have any explanation as to how does the first version can work on a system.